# GeoServer in Tomcat doesn't get update shapefiles from PostGis

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have two GeoServers running in the same machine Ubuntu Server 9.04. GeoServer V2.0.1 is running with Jetty and another GeoServer V2.0.0 is Tomcat. Both of them are using the same PostGis datastore.

When I post new shapefile via Rest api to GeoServer in Jetty, The GeoServer in Tomcat doesn't get update shapefile from PostGis.

It may have the way to tell GeoServer in Tomcat in configuration or service to reload shapefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue just reinstall GeoServer to the newer version 2.0.1 is Tomcat.
It seems GeoServer V2.0.0 has the bug.